# Capistrano 3.5 Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ssh, capistrano

Deploy `Rails 4.2.0` app with `capistrano 3.5` and received the error:

Here is the line for ssh in `Deploy.rb`:

```
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/mykey.ppk) }
```

`mykey.ppk` is the key used on putty to login to the server (aws instance).

Here is the error of `bundle exec cap production deploy`

```
cap aborted!
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user myname@IP
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-3.1.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:246:in `start'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.10.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `call'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.10.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `with'
```

The current version of net-ssh is `3.1.1`. There is a post about downgrading `net-ssh` to `2.7.0' on Capistrano 3.4. However Capistrano 3.5 requires`net-ssh`2.8.0 or above. Tried`net-ssh 3.1.0` and the problem is the same. What else could fix the problem with Cap 3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after replacing `mykey.ppk` with `mykey.pem`